# How to select text from textbox in ios app and click on text using appium

Tags: python, selenium, appium, appium-ios, python-appium

I can write text to textbox in iOS app using appium as

```
editTextBox = driver.find_element_by_xpath("....")
editTextBox.send_keys(text)
```

The text is web link, how can I click on link?
I think I can select text and then click?

Comment: you want to click on the entered text?

Comment: yes basically I want to click on url link. For android I could use `adb` to do so. But for iOS I didn't find any similar option so I thought I will paste the link it textBox and then click on it.